# PHP ZipArchive with accent chars in filenames

Tags: php, windows-7, php-ziparchive, non-ascii-characters

I'm creating ZIP archive on **UNIX** system using PHP 5.3.10 with Zip version 1.12.5 and Libzip version 0.11.2:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$test_zip = "./test.zip";
if ($zip->open($test_zip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===TRUE)
{
    $zip->addFromString("Liste client à exporter.txt","Content line 1\nContent line 2\n");
    $zip->close();

    if(file_exists($test_zip))
    {
        header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header ("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($test_zip));
        header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"");
        header ("Cache-Control: max-age=60");
        readfile($test_zip);
        unlink ($test_zip);
    }
}
?>
```

When I open generated ZIP file test.zip on **Windows 7** using internal ZIP, I see file in archive like "Liste client +а exporter.txt" instead of "Liste client à exporter.txt".
But if open it for example with 7z, file name is correct, with accent.
PHP file has UTF-8 encoding.

**SOLVED**
Problem was in Windows 7 (patch KB2704299)

[File names are corrupted after you decompress a .zip file in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2704299)

Comment: zip file opened in decrypted format?

Comment: Not understand what you meant. It is opens automatically after download. Same effect when double click on zip file.

Comment: what is the exact problem

Comment: Probleb is that when archive opened with internal Windows arhciver, it shows filenames without accents.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (i'm french so the problem with accent i know about).

To avoid this problem i use an external zip command.

For Linux :

```
exec("cd \"".$the_directory_you want_to_zip."\" && zip -0 -r \"".$path_zip."\" .");
```

Comment: It does not help. Same effect: with internal windows upzipping the same +a. Using 7z names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about about the current state of Windows 10 and Php7 today but in case someone still have problem with zip accent on Windows.

You need to convert file name to `IBM850` when zipping and back to `UTF8, ISO-8859-1, CP1252` when extracting from zip.

```php
//zipping
$relativePath = iconv('UTF-8', 'IBM850', $relativePath);
$zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);

//extracting
$relativePath = iconv('IBM850', 'UTF-8', $zip->getNameIndex($i));
$zip->renameIndex($i, $relativePath);
$zip->extractTo($destination, $relativePath);
```